# Corrupted .deb files on enterprise network

Tags: curl, hash, apt, system-administration, dpkg

I use Ubuntu 16.04 on several machines at work.

On each of them, certain Debian packages are not correctly downloaded (corrupted).

Example with apt-get:

```
$ sudo apt-get install traceroute
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-53 linux-headers-4.4.0-53-generic linux-image-4.4.0-53-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  traceroute
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 45.5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 177 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 traceroute amd64 1:2.0.21-1 [45.5 kB]
Err:1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 traceroute amd64 1:2.0.21-1
  Hash Sum mismatch
Fetched 44.8 kB in 0s (477 kB/s)   
E: Failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/traceroute/traceroute_2.0.21-1_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Example of manual install:

```
$ curl http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/traceroute/traceroute_2.0.21-1_amd64.deb -o traceroute_2.0.21-1_amd64.deb
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
 95 45488   95 43538    0     0   353k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  354k
curl: (18) transfer closed with 1950 bytes remaining to read
$ sudo dpkg -i traceroute_2.0.21-1_amd64.deb 
(Reading database ... 248576 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack traceroute_2.0.21-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking traceroute (1:2.0.21-1) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): cannot copy archive member from 'traceroute_2.0.21-1_amd64.deb' to decompressor pipe: unexpected end of file or stream
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: unexpected end of input
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive traceroute_2.0.21-1_amd64.deb (--install):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/lib/libsupp.a' to '/usr/lib/libsupp.a.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 traceroute_2.0.21-1_amd64.deb
```

As you can see, the file is not correctly downloaded with curl: curl: `(18) transfer closed with 1950 bytes remaining to read`. wget also does not solve the problem.

**Note that through a 4G connection share, the command works perfectly well.**

I tried on Ubuntu 16.04 or 16.10 through docker: same problem.

I changed the Ubuntu repository (main, uk, it, etc.): same problem.

I am not the enterprise sys admin so I cannot check what's going on in this (windows) enterprise network.

Something corrupts certain file types, here `.deb`.

Which work-around could I test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a work-around: using an **https** Ubuntu repository.

[This page](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/3q53kc/list_of_ubuntu_repository_mirrors_available_over/) shows a list of Ubuntu repositories which are accessible through https.

I used https://mirror.vorboss.net/ubuntu-archive/ which worked perfectly well.

In conclusion, I think that my enterprise network is "protected" by a firewall which refuses to let me download certain (always the same, systematically) .deb files.
This firewall could make a signature of the new downloaded file, detect it as a "menace" and refuse to send me its last part.